# Azure 1.4 / VS 2010 Default Web Browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, browser

I'm running VS2010 SP1 and Azure 1.4 Tools on Windows 7 SP1. My system default web browser is Chrome. My Visual Studio default web browser is Firefox (right click on .aspx file - Browse with - set default).

When I hit CTRL+F5 (start without debugging), my cloud service web role starts in Chrome.

When I hit F5 (start with debugging), my cloud service web role opens two windows - one in Chrome, one in Firefox.

I tried `devenv /resetsettings` to no avail. How do I make VS honor its default?

Comment: There is an option in the project properties page of the Web role for which endpoint to launch (HTTP, HTTPS, or both) when running locally.  Are both checked?  What happens if you only have one checked?

Comment: Only HTTP is checked. I don't have any SSL cert in the project and so HTTPS isn't an option.

Comment: I wonder where VS stores this setting. Registry? Some file?

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio stores this info in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\browsers.xml. Deleting it seems to just fall back to system default--I still can't override it in VS. I wonder if Azure tools store it separately.

Comment: I also tried deleting the ccproj.user and .suo files. No change.

Comment: One more comment - the tooling upgrade did not cause this. I believe that it happened when I collapsed two web projects into one and re-associated the web role with the 'new' project (the role was previously associated with the now-deleted web project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this doesn't make sense - it has fixed the problem on two out of two cases: enable the Silverlight debugger on the web project.

- Right click / properties on web project
- Web tab
- Enable ASP.NET and Silverlight

After ticking the Silverlight box, F5 and CTRL+F5 started behaving normally, respecting my Visual Studio default browser.

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't make sense to me either ... but it seemed to work. thx.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2010 uses the default browser when you press F5 in a web project, then it caches what your default browser is in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\browsers.xml, you can find this exact file in your registry under  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\WebBrowser\ConfigTimestamp\CacheFilePath . Try to change your default web browser.

Comment: I tried deleting that file as well as the entire WebBrowser registry key, and then restarting Visual Studio. That "should" force it back to using defaults, right? I have tried changing my system default as well as the Visual Studio default (right click on .aspx -> browse with) multiple times. No matter what: CTRL+F5 starts the system default browser. F5 starts BOTH the system default AND the VS default. This happens in all (I've tried two) Azure solutions with a web role as the startup project.

Comment: Update: after deleting the file and registry key, if I don't reset the Visual Studio browser, then it's less screwed up with just my system default (as in, only one instance starts when I hit F5). This is an improvement, but not a resolution.